# Add new Property in Jsonb column by calculating some of its properties Using Postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have a jsonb column such that:

```
| id       | fee                                    |
|----------|----------------------------------------|
| 1        |  "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "10"}]"  |
| 2        |  "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "999"}]" |
| 3        |  []                                    |
```

And I want to calculate the Value filed and add new property in the same `fee` column such that:

```
ROUND((Value / 1.07),2)
```

I tried this below code but its not working.

```
update plans 
set excess_fees = jsonb_set(plans.excess_fees, '{0, ValueExclGst}', 
                            (select cast(round(cast(VALUE as decimal), 2) as text)  
                             from jsonb_array_elements(plans.excess_fees->'Value') as VALUE));
```

The output looks like this:

```
| id | fee |
|----|-----|
| 1  | "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "10", "ValueExclGst":"9.35"}]" |
| 2  | "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "999", "ValueExclGst": "933.64"}]" |
| 3  | [] |
```

How shall I do in Postgres since I am new to Jsonb?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb_array_elements` and `jsonb_set` would come handy for this. A working query:

```
WITH fee_json AS
(
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(fee) as json_data FROM plans
),
updated_rows AS (
  SELECT id,
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_set(json_data, '{ValueExclGst}', CAST(round(CAST(json_data->>'Value' AS NUMERIC)/1.07, 2) as text)::jsonb)
    ) as updated_json
  FROM
    fee_json
  GROUP BY
    id
)
UPDATE plans SET fee = u.updated_json
FROM updated_rows u
WHERE plans.id = u.id;
```

The query works in these phases:

1. Create a `fee_json` auxiliary statement using CTE by deflating the `fee` array column. Now `fee_json` has a column `json_data` with all the deflated jsonb objects along with the corresponding `id`.
2. Create another `updated_rows` auxiliary statement using the values from `fee_json`. In this statement, we're inserting a new value `ValueExclGst` in the jsonb using the value from `Value` field in jsonb. We array aggregate all such jsonb objects by `id` using `jsonb_agg`.
3. We update the value from `udpated_rows` using the `id` field in our `plans` table.

A working [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXTZLRZ3LdZVwq8G2XgcqW/0) for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I need to save decimal value into text so I change a bit as 

```to_jsonb(round(CAST(json_data->>'Value' AS NUMERIC)/1.07, 2)::text)```

BTW, if I want to remove the new added property in case I wanna roll back, how to remove that property -> {ValueExclGst} ?

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach I found out to solve the given problem. Yet it only work for first index which means it will work for all the **id{1,2,3}** but for **id{1}**, it will just update the first index.

| id | fee |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "10"}, {"Step": "step1", "Value": "10"}]" |
| 2 | "[{"Step": "step1", "Value": "999"}]" |
| 3 | [] |

```
UPDATE fee pl SET excess_fees = jsonb_set(pl.excess_fees, '{0, ValueExclGst}', to_jsonb(gstExclVal.exclValue::text))
FROM (
       SELECT ps.id, ROUND((Cast( arr.item_object->>'Value' as numeric) / 1.07),2) as exclValue
       FROM fee ps, jsonb_array_elements(ps.excess_fees) with ordinality arr(item_object, position)
     ) AS gstExclVal
WHERE pl.id = gstExclVal.id;
```

To rollback programmatically, we can use below code snippets :

```
UPDATE fee pl SET excess_fees = excess_fee.orginal_excess_fee
FROM (
    SELECT fee.p_id, jsonb_agg(fee.item) as orginal_excess_fee from (
    SELECT fee.id as p_id, (arr.item_object - 'ValueExclGst') as item , arr.position as pos
    FROM fee, jsonb_array_elements(excess_fees) with ordinality arr(item_object, position)
    ) as fee group by fee.p_id
 ) AS excess_fee where pl.id= excess_fee.p_id;
```